# Pyspark cannot find java binary

Tags: java, linux, shell, apache-spark, pyspark

I am a student who is new to Linux and Spark. When I try to launch Pyspark with

```
~/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6$ ./bin/pyspark
```

returns

```
/home/di/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-class: line 86: /user/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. I thought there's wrong with JAVA Path
And I checked my java with

```
$ java -version
```

returns

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

It seems like Java works well. Now I am confused what's wrong with it. Can any body help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: Does `/user/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java` really exist? I think your `java` command is linked to another java bin. You can check it by typing `$ which java`

Comment: Make sure you have correct `$JAVA_HOME`